# Progressive reveal with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have nested unordered list.

```
<ul id="catalogue">
    <li>List
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1.1</li>
                    <li>Item 1.2
                        <ul>
                            <li>Item 1.2.1</li>
                            <li>Item 1.2.2
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Item 1.2.2.1</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>Item 1.2.3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Item 1.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

At the beginning only the very top level shows, but if you click on each LI, if there's a child UL in it, it should display the next lever, and so on. If you click on the same LI again, the level below should become hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#catalogue li').each(function () {
        $(this).contents().first().wrap("<span/>")
    });
    $('#catalogue li > span').addClass('brd');

    $('ul').hide();
    $('#catalogue').show();

    $('#catalogue li').click(function () {
        var nxt = $(this).children('ul:first')
        if ($(nxt).is(":visible")) {
            $(nxt).slideUp();
        } else {
            $(nxt).slideDown();
        }
        $(this).parent().show();
    });

});
```

If a user clicks on a sibling LI and it has a child UL, that UL should show but any sibling's ones should close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the event from propagating to the parent. Clicking on each `li` will invoke its own click handler and the event will propagate to its parent `li` invoke its handler and so on. So you can just stop it at one level by using `event.stopPropagation()`. And you can use `slideToggle` to toggle the current state of the element.

Try:

```
$('#tree li').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul:first').slideToggle();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h6mq6/)**

And if you want to slide up while clicked on its sibling then,

```
$('#tree li').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.children('ul:first').slideToggle().end()
               .siblings().children('ul:visible').slideUp();
    //Code Broken down
    //$this.children('ul:first').slideToggle();
    //$this.siblings().children('ul:visible').slideUp();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46w29/)**

Comment: This is very cool. I think the second example is a lot closer to what I was trying to accomplish. One tiny thing... It will collapse the siblings but not the children of the siblings. Is it because of the e.stopPropogation? Can it be enabled one way, down? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @santa No. events bubble up the DOM tree, i.e travel upwards that is what we are preventing here. You could try something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/39q7k/